# IE stylesheet not loading entirely

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a small issue with IE. I'm working on a site nothing fancy just some static html pages (around 35), I am using bootstrap as a skeleton, font-awesome, Animate.css,responsive styles, Jvectormaps, footables, custom styling ect... 
I usually write and include separate css files to keep things easy to maintain, everything's working well until I decided to merge all files in a single one because I need to test if my pages load faster.

After doing so IE seems not processing the whole stylesheet file because when I go the developers tool then check my merged CSS file I can see it is like cut in half. This is weird , I am sure not sure why IE is leaving out all the rest.

SO i split the main file into two separate ones, now everything is back to normal

In Chrome / Firefox I do not face this issue so I am certain it has something to do with IE(9/8). Does anyone know Why? if it is realted to file size? (450Kb) Is there a way to include all file in one or I should keep separate ones?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi can you post the output from console?

Comment: Output? Im not sure if you referring to errors which there is not any.. If you talking about the CSS file, I saved a copy and compared both.. as I said, when I split my file into , the browser seems to read the two parts..

Comment: How many stylesheets are you including in the page ?

Comment: @Awena Im asking you to post what the problem is in the css console

Comment: @Freez before merging files, around 9 files + the page-specific file, after merging files I have the main CSS file + the responsive one (2)..

Comment: @Kyle Did you read the question ? What does the console output has to do with this ?

Comment: @Awena Did i read the question? if we could see what the problem is maybe we could help. "when I go the developers tool then check my merged CSS file I can see it is like cut in half." what does that actually mean??

Comment: @Awena Is it possible that your stylesheet contains up to 4095 rules? (IE6-9 limit)

Comment: Yes it might, was not aware there is a limit

Comment: @Freez where did you get this limit from? Would you share the link

Comment: sorry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx

Comment: I have 4739 , I checked with the link austin provided , that seems to be the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be hitting the limits on how many elements IE 9 and down can display. Use a site like the one below to see if you are below the count limit:

http://snippet.bevey.com/css/selectorCount.php

If you are using Grunt in your project, there are tasks that can split your css up automatically to fix this issue.

Comment: Results say : 4739 (over 4096 limit)

Comment: As a workaround, Can I use the main file to import the rest ? Will the affect the performance ?

Comment: You can either split your css files out (ex bootstrap is separate) or split the entire compiled sheet into multiples. The extra sheets would then be put in an IE only call so they aren't loaded on other browsers

Answer (score 1):

You may be encountering some of the CSS limits that are related to IE. Microsoft has changed/increased/removed these limits in more recent versions, but you may still encounter these limits.
There are many possibilities such as which IE version is being used, and what document compatibility mode is specified.
If your pages have an older document compatibility mode specified, you will encounter some of the lower limits that limited older versions of IE.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781508.aspx for more details.